# SOAP embedding signing, error moving to production

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to set up an embedded signing session with SOAP.  In the demo environment everything works perfectly and I have passed the API Certification.

When I'm trying to move things over to the live I can create the envelope with no issues.  When I make the call to RequestRecipientToken I get the "One or both of Username and Password are invalid." error back.

I'm at a complete loss here since everything works perfectly in the demo environment.

I've added a new Service Reference to https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0 and changed all the code to use this.  I've checked my accounts and login information and everything is correct.

I can create the envelope just fine and they show up under my account in the live Docusign site.

I've checked my base url and it is na2, but the https://na2.docusign.net/api/3.0 show forbidden to me.

Anything I'm missing from simply moving working code from demo to live?

Comment: It sounds like you've done everything correctly, I'm wondering if it's related to the sending account credentials.  With DocuSign signing is always free and you do not need an account to sign, however you DO need an account to create envelopes and request signing tokens (URLs) for others.  When you make the API call to request the recipient token are you positive you are using credentials of a user who has a valid production account?  Can you login to the DocuSign Web Application successfully using those credentials?

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Yes I can log into the account with the credentials requesting the recipient token.  I can pull the envelope status and create envelopes and it seems do everything except request the token for embedded signing.

Comment: Hmm ok then maybe it's a difference between how your demo account was configured and your production account is configured.  By default, developer sandboxes (i.e. demo accounts) have embedded signing enabled so that devs can test, however only certain production accounts have it enabled (for instance, you can't do embedded signing with an Individual account).  Can you reach out to your DocuSign account manager and ensure that Embedding is enabled in your production (NA2) account?

Comment: Are you passing an x509 with the request? In the Demo environment DocuSign does not require an in session certificate. However, it's a requirement in the Production environments.

Comment: I am not, hopefully that is the problem.  I'll add the cert and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: That was it, adding x509 fixed this issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docusign Production account setting: Don't Enforce In Session Certificate. Resolved this issue.

Reference: 
DocuSign API Best Practices
https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/documents/SOAP_REST_API_Best_Practices(with_Connect_Guide).pdf

Answer (score 1):

Adding x509 certificate to my request fixed the issue as Rickey S suggested.